# How to bring back rows where no result set is found

Tags: sql-server

1. Here is my problem I am trying to get some counts on ID's that did not match.
2. My expected result set is the replicationTime column (e.g. 201701, 201702...), when I do my count I only have NULL values for 201702, but not 201701...is there a way to bring back all the existing replicationTime values (i.e. 201701 AND 201702) but padded the count column with a zero or a NULL? I basically need to bring back two rows, but only one comes back which is the one that had no matches

```
select replicationTime, count(*) as CountsForNoMatches
from table 
where ID IS NULL
Group By ReplicationTime
```

3. I have tried using ISNULL... but It is not bringing back anything other than the same row.
4. Also, keep in mind this is the portion of a Subquery and it serves a larger picture in the overall query where I need all rows and not just one otherwise my result set returns nothing.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so others can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
select replicationTime, sum(case when ID is null then 1 else 0 end) as CountsForNoMatches
from table 
Group By ReplicationTime
```

or

```
select replicationTime, max(case when ID is null then 1 else 0 end) as CountsForNoMatches
from table 
Group By ReplicationTime
```

if you just want to know if there is some row with a null ID for that ReplicationTime.

Comment: so, I tried these and it did not work. I am still getting a result set with one row for 201702, and on the latter I get a 1 but I am interested in the actual count. What I need is to keep the ReplicationTime rows as shells even then no result set for that count were found. So, since I know there were no matches for 201701, I would like it displayed as    201701 NULL

Comment: If there are no rows in your table for 201701 you'll have to introduce a calendar table.